# Securing BIP39 Phrases and Password Manager Master Password

Tags: password-management, pgp, yubikey, cryptocurrency

I am looking for a review of the solution to store my Ledger Nano S BIP39 recovery phrase as well as my password manager usage.
This solution is mostly based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqrAzBAi64c&ab_channel=CharlesHoskinson) video.

[image]

Few points that I think require explanation

1. Emergency access process for Bitwarden explained [here](https://community.bitwarden.com/t/emergency-access/115/116#). Essentially if I get hit by a bus, my partner will be able to request recovery and if I don't reject approval via email she will get full access to Bitwarden.
2. Devices I am planning to purchase: 2 x [Yubico - YubiKey 5C NFC](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08DHL1YDL/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1); 1 x [Apricorn ASK3-NXC-4GB](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08D3JY9ZS/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
3. [Create backup Yubikey with identical PGP keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/181551/create-backup-yubikey-with-identical-pgp-keys)
4. Restore of Bitwarden from Google Drive + Dropbox tested successfully.

Questions

1. Are there any major flaws that you see with this approach?
2. Any further improvements that can be added in terms of security and/or usability?
3. Any recovery process flaws?

Many thanks in advance.